# Replace previously generated content in Javascript based on user input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button on that perfroms the collatz conjecture with the push of a button, and takes in the user's input. It then prints out the steps as a list into a `p` tag. I wanted to know how I would override the previously created steps, as I have noticed calling the method again adds to the end of the previous list.

The main reason I'm using a list is for readability, so I don't want to get rid of it unless there's a better way of doing this.

```
//collatz function
function collatz (){
    var step = 0;
    var inputCollatz = prompt("What number do you want to add?")
    if (inputCollatz <= 1){
        document.getElementById("collatz").innerHTML = "No steps required, already less than or equal to 1.";
    }
    else if(isNaN(inputCollatz)){
        document.getElementById("collatz").innerHTML = "Please add a number.";
    }
    else if (inputCollatz.toString().indexOf('.') != -1){
        document.getElementById("collatz").innerHTML = "Whole numbers please!";
    }
    else{
        while(inputCollatz > 1){
            //needed help w/ ternary operators, still need practice with it
            inputCollatz = inputCollatz % 2 ? 3 * inputCollatz + 1 : inputCollatz / 2;
            step++;
            var item = document.createElement("li");
            var text = document.createTextNode(inputCollatz);
            item.appendChild(text);
            var list = document.getElementById("collatz");
            list.appendChild(item);
        }
        document.getElementById("steps").innerHTML = "Number of steps: " + step.toString();
    }
}
```

This is the button in `html`.

```
    <button onclick="collatz()">Find the number of steps.</button><br/>
        <br/>
        <div id="collatz"></div>
        <br/>
        <div id="steps"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was suggested to clear out the `collatz` div before each loop, which worked.

```
...
else {
    document.getElementById("collatz").innerHTML = '';
    while(inputCollatz > 1) {
    ....
```